# How to execute union query in zf2 where i m using tablegateway?

Tags: postgresql, zend-framework2, union

How to execute the following query

`select * from table1 union select * from table2`

in zend-framework2 where i am using tablegateway?  In the documentation of zf2,they didn't give any details about union query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try -

```
$select1 = new Select('table1');
[.... rest of the code ....]


$select2 = new Select('table2');
[.... rest of the code ....]

$select1->combine($select2); //This will create the required SQL union statement.
```

---

To get count of the two tables you have to use a bit of SQL rather then tableGateway -

```
$sql = new Sql($this->tableGateway->adapter);
$select_string = $sql->getSqlStringForSqlObject($select1);

$sql_string = 'SELECT * FROM (' . $select_string . ') AS select_union';
$statement = $this->tableGateway->adapter->createStatement($sql_string);
$resultSet = $statement->execute();
$total_records = count($resultSet);
```

`$resultSet` gives data.

`$total_records` gives total no. of records.

Comment: Thanks for ur help.. based on certain conditions(using where statement) i wil get count in table1[eg:10] ,in table2[eg:20]..now i joined two tables i m nt clear how to get count after joining the table..

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check.

Comment: i able to get the count now.i want to include "where condition" which i have written in zend\db\sql\where..how to append $where to $statement

Comment: Still couldn't find the way to convert the `$where` to string and append. I guess for now, you will have to work with writing the condition in raw SQL and append.